# Same xml controller for different activities

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

I'm kind of new in Android and i'd like to know if there is a way of displaying a xml file (with the same 'controller') from different activities?
In other words, I'd like to display a list of CardViews with the same content and listeners in two different activities (exactly the same way). What is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

There's ways to do this if I understand right.

1. You can use same xml in different Activities.
2. You can start same Activity twice.
3. You can use fragment to display same content.